# Custom asdict method for dataclasses

Tags: python

I want to dump a dataclass instance into a dict by omitting some of the attrs.
I used the metadata parameter of the field method.
Also I want any bytes object to be turned into a hex string.
What do you think?

```
def asdict(obj):
    """ use with dataclass only """
    dict_ = {}
    for k, v in obj.__dataclass_fields__.items():
        if v.metadata.get('is_exported') != False:
            dict_[k] = getattr(obj, k)
        if type(getattr(obj,k)) == bytes:
            dict_[k] = getattr(obj, k).hex()
    return dict_


@dataclass
class Password:
    password: str = field(metadata = {'is_exported' : False})
```

**EDIT:**
I've finally been to the source code of python and tinkered with the dataclasses module and modified slightly the asdict method (the _adict_inner is wrapped by asdict):

```
def _asdict_inner(obj, dict_factory):
    obj_type = type(obj)
    if obj_type in _ATOMIC_TYPES:
        return obj
    elif hasattr(obj_type, _FIELDS):
        # dataclass instance: fast path for the common case
        if dict_factory is dict:
            return {
                f.name: _asdict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name), dict)
                for f in fields(obj) if f.metadata.get('is_exported') != False # here is the addon
            }
        else:
            return dict_factory([
                (f.name, _asdict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name), dict_factory))
                for f in fields(obj) if f.metadata.get('is_exported') != False # here is the addon
            ])
```

Done a few test and it works flawlessly so far. Now I have a custom dataclasses module that allows me to omit some attrs from the dict export function.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for the method that already does this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict)?

Comment: sure, but it is not possible to exclude an attr on demand

Comment: Is this eventually exported to JSON, or something else?

Comment: It can but not mandatory

Answer (score 9):

Don't `type() == bytes`; use `isinstance`. More broadly, though, bytes-to-hex conversion doesn't seem like it should be in this function; you can do another iteration on the dictionary in a separate function to accomplish this. If this is for export to JSON, the best place to do this is a [custom encoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder). If this *isn't* being done for JSON, I question why it's being done at all.

`asdict` is not a good name, since it conflicts with the stock implementation of `dataclasses.asdict`.

I think it's a good idea to explicitly fill in a `True` default for the metadata `get()` call.

Write unit tests.

Add PEP484 type hints (not that those can be entirely specific, here).

You should probably leverage the built-in `fields` instead of iterating on a dunder.

### Suggested

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from typing import Any


def export(obj) -> dict[str, Any]:
    """ use with dataclass only """
    return {
        field.name: getattr(obj, field.name)
        for field in fields(obj)
        if field.metadata.get('is_exported', True)
    }


@dataclass
class Password:
    username: str = field(metadata={'is_exported': True})
    password: str = field(metadata={'is_exported': False})
    has_default: float


def test() -> None:
    actual = export(Password('bob', 'password', 3.2))
    expected = {
        'username': 'bob',
        'has_default': 3.2,
    }
    assert actual == expected


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Nice! My idea was to overload the dict_factory built-in method, but your solution seems nice as well. What about overloading this method by adding a check of the metadata of the field? Then I can take advantage of the recursion as well (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/37f5d06b1bf830048c09ed967bb2cda945d56541/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1334)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by overloading. In the strictest sense, Python does not have signature overloading. Perhaps you mean overriding. And as for recursion... I guess it's possible, but you haven't demonstrated realistic data structures that call for it, so I'll remain skeptical that that's a good idea.

Comment: You're right, sorry I am not native English speaker, I meant overriding. I will try and will get back to post my code

Comment: Add edit in my initial question with some code.